Problem with avr-g++ 13.3.0 passing const char array as parameter in ATmega4809 (40 pins)
The following code doesn't work in ATmega4809:

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void f(const char str[])
{
    if (str[0] == 'a'){ // <-- here is the problem!!! The program thinks str[0] != 'a'
        PORTC.OUT |= PIN0_bm;
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTC.OUT &= ~PIN0_bm;
        _delay_ms(500);

    } else { // blink a led in pin PC1
    
        PORTC.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTC.OUT &= ~PIN1_bm;
        _delay_ms(500);

    }

}

int main()
{
    PORTC.DIR |= PIN0_bm; // init pin PC0 
    PORTC.DIR |= PIN1_bm; // init pin PC1

    while (1) { f("abc"); }

}


When I pass a const char array to a function (in the code when I pass str to function f) the value of the string is wrong (in this case, the value of str[0] it's not 'a' but a different char). To implement a minimal program to show the problem I'm using 2 leds: if str[0] is 'a' (the right value) one led blinks; if it is not, other led blinks. The problem is that the wrong led blinks.
I detect this problem in a different program that compile and work fine with atmega328p but has this weird behavior with atmega4809 (of 40 pins).
What am I doing wrong? It is a compiler problem?
================
I am compiling it with avr-g++ 13.3.0:
avr-g++ -Os -std=c++23 -Wall -pedantic  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fshort-enums  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -save-temps -fverbose-asm -DMCU=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=2666667UL  -mmcu=atmega4809 -c -o test.o test.cpp


I'm using the atmega4809 of 40 pins. I know that I have to initialize pins PB[5:0] and PC[7:6] and I do it in my program. I don't show the init function in the previous code because the program behaves the same calling that init function or not.
============
I'm not used to read assembler, but here (I think) is the relevant asm code:
The string "abc":
.LC0:
    .string "abc"
    .section    .text.startup.main,"ax",@progbits

The call of f("abc"):
    ldi r24,lo8(.LC0)    ; ,
    ldi r25,hi8(.LC0)    ; ,
    call _Z1fPKc     ; 

and the if of f function:
    .section    .text._Z1fPKc,"ax",@progbits
.global _Z1fPKc
    .type   _Z1fPKc, @function
_Z1fPKc:
.L__stack_usage = 0
 ;  main.cpp:43:     if (str[0] == 'a'){
    movw r30,r24     ; , tmp62
    ld r24,Z         ;  *str_9(D), *str_9(D)
    cpi r24,lo8(97)  ;  *str_9(D),
    brne .L3         ; ,
    // blink PC0
    // ...

==========
EDIT: Adding the result of avr-objdump -D test.elf (relevant parts, only):
Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000414c <_end-0x7fe6b4>:
    414c:   61 62           ori r22, 0x21   ; 33
    414e:   63 00           .word   0x0063  ; ????

Why avr-objdump writes those signs: ???? <-- is this the problem?
Call of f in main:
 13e:   8c e4           ldi r24, 0x4C   ; 76
 140:   91 e4           ldi r25, 0x41   ; 65
 142:   0e 94 5c 00     call    0xb8    ; 0xb8 <_Z1fPKc>

Function f (till if...):
000000b8 <_Z1fPKc>:
  b8:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  ba:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
  bc:   81 36           cpi r24, 0x61   ; 97

=========
EDIT2: I've written the same program in atmega328p and it works fine. The difference in the result of avr-objdump -D between atmega328p and atmega4809 is that in the case of atmega328p the "abc" string is store in the .data section, while in the case of atmega4809 it stores it in the .rodata section.
==========
EDIT3: The problem is with the .rodata section.
If I change the code using a variable str:
const char str[] = "abc";

and then call f(str) the program doesn't work, but if I force to write str into the .data section:
const char str[] __attribute__((section(".data")))  = "abc";

the progam works.
Is this a problem with avr-gcc 13.3.0?

Constants live in program memory (flash) but the code uses ld to read ram. It's unclear how you build and run the program but it sounds like you somehow omitted the startup code that normally copies constants to ram. Alternatively change your function to accept a progmem string directly.

@Jester Atmega4809 is one of the new architecture AVRs (closer to xmega) with flat memory model emulation, so unless it created flash pointer instead of normal one, it should be fine.

@KIIV thanks, did not know that. Then maybe the relevant section (.rodata?) was omitted during linking.

@Jester how can I check in the .elf if the .rodata was omitted or not?

objdump -h or readelf -S

Executing: objdump -s -j .rodata xx.elf I get:  Contents of section .rodata:  414c 61626300                             abc.

@Jester Executing: objdump -h or xx.elf -S  it answers    2 .rodata       00000004  0000414c  0000014c  000001c0  2**0  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA, and some lines after objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!

Looks good. Can you check if that 414c address is what got put into the ldi r24?

@Jester I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do that. What commands or file do I have to run or read?

objdump -d should be able to show it, if you can find it :)

@Jester avr-objdump -d answers: 13e: 8c e4  ldi r24, 0x4C and the next line 140: 91 e4     ldi r25, 0x41 ; 65 (it seems it loads 0x414c, but it's the order right?)

That looks correct as well. Strange.

@Jester I've just added the result of avr-objdump -D test.elf to the question. It answers with ???? in the .rodata section. Maybe there is the problem?

No, the ???? is just because you asked to disassemble data.

@Jester comparing atmega328p result with atmega4809 it seems the only difference is that in the first case the compiler writes the string "abc" in the .data section, while in the second case it writes in the .rodata section

Maybe you are missing to upload .rodata? See you other same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79141434/avr-gcc-atmega4809-problem-with-rodata-section/79142028?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#79142028
